# New Python Programmer how can I do this easier/better?

Tags: python

Rules of project: http://www.reddit.com/r/beginnerprojects/comments/19kxre/project_99_bottles_of_beer_on_the_wall_lyrics/

My project code in **Python 3.4:**

```
for x in reversed (range(2, 100)):
print(x,end="") 
print (" bottles beer on the wall take one down ",end="")
print ("pass it round now ",end="") 
print (x-1)

b = 1
c = 0
print (b,end="")
print (" bottle beer pass around now ", end="")
print (c,end="")
print (" bottles left ! aw man I get no beer :(")`
```

Comment: please specify exact problem without necessity in external docs..

Comment: And rethink your indentation..

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-python-1327.html

As the comments said it, be really careful with indentation!
If you want a version without indentation... http://www.99-bottles-of-beer.net/language-python-748.html

Be really creative, use these links for inspiration only.